# VBA AutoCAD Compile Error variable not defined

Tags: vba, autocad

I have a .dvb file created in VBA, I am getting a compile error stating:

> variable not defined

There are two modules of code one for the form and one for common dialog. The error I am getting is for common dialog code that has been swiped from somewhere else for handling Browse and adding drawings.

Common dialog code Module extract:

```
 Public Function GetFiles( _
ByVal sInitFolder As String, _
ByVal sTitle As String, _
ByVal sFilter As String, _
ByVal nFilterIndex As Integer) As String()

strReturn = FileBrowseOpen(sInitFolder, sTitle, sFilter, nFilterIndex, True) 'code failing here "compile error variable not defined"
GetFiles = Split(strReturn, ",")

End Function
```

Form Code module extract:

```
Private Sub cmdAddDwg_Click()

Dim initFolder As String
Dim filter As String
Dim fileNames() As String
Dim i As Integer

initFolder = ThisDrawing.Path
filter = "AutoCAD Drawing Files (*.dwg)|*.dwg|All Files (*.*)|*.*"

fileNames = GetFiles(initFolder, "Select Drawing Files", filter, 0)
If UBound(fileNames) > 0 Then
    For i = 1 To UBound(fileNames)
        lstDwgList.AddItem fileNames(0) & "\" & fileNames(i)
    Next
End If

End Sub
```

My VBA knowledge is limited at best.

Thanks in advance much appreciated.

Comment: `strReturn` is not defined, so you get a message "Variable not defined". Define `strReturn` and you will get rid of the message.

Comment: Thanks mate ` Dim strReturn As String` did the trick

Answer (score 1):

Either define your variable `strReturn` as a string:

```
Public Function GetFiles ( _
    ByVal sInitFolder As String, _
    ByVal sTitle As String, _
    ByVal sFilter As String, _
    ByVal nFilterIndex As Integer) As String()

    Dim strReturn As String ' This line was missing
    strReturn = FileBrowseOpen(sInitFolder, sTitle, sFilter, nFilterIndex, True)
    GetFiles = Split(strReturn, ",")
End Function
```

Or rewrite that section of the code to omit the `strReturn` variable entirely:

```
Public Function GetFiles ( _
    ByVal sInitFolder As String, _
    ByVal sTitle As String, _
    ByVal sFilter As String, _
    ByVal nFilterIndex As Integer) As String()

    GetFiles = Split(FileBrowseOpen(sInitFolder, sTitle, sFilter, nFilterIndex, True), ",")
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks Lee, You're every where..... is there a way of making a label lbldwglst show the amount of files in a listbox lstdwglist? with a prefix text string in the label "Number of drawings" ? I have tried listcount but keep getting compile errors, And ive only started learning VBA

Comment: Thanks Lee that is a much better way of writing the code. As stated above I have an 'add drawing' button name *cmdAddDwg* that uses common dialog to browse and select files and populate in a listbox *lstDwgList* is it possible to create a label *lbldwglst* at bottom of userform *frmMultiScript* that populates a count of the items in the listbox?

Comment: `Private Sub cmdAddDwg_Click()

    Dim initFolder As String
    Dim filter As String
    Dim fileNames() As String
    Dim i As Integer
    initFolder = lastPath 'gets last known location
    filter = "AutoCAD Drawing Files (*.dwg)|*.dwg|All Files (*.*)|*.*"
    
    fileNames = GetFiles(initFolder, "Select Drawing Files", filter, 0)
    If UBound(fileNames) > 0 Then
        For i = 1 To UBound(fileNames)
            lstDwgList.AddItem fileNames(0) & "\" & fileNames(i)
        Next
        
    End If
End Sub`  @Lee Mac

Comment: @stuboy You're welcome - I'm glad that my answer helped. Your additional comments may be better answered as a separate question (this is a Q&A site, not a forum).

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub cmdAddDwg_Click()
Dim initFolder As String
Dim filter As String
Dim fileNames() As String
Dim i As Integer

'initFolder = ThisDrawing.Path 'gets dwg folder path
initFolder = lastPath 'gets last known location
filter = "AutoCAD Drawing Files (*.dwg)|*.dwg|All Files (*.*)|*.*"

fileNames = GetFiles(initFolder, "Select Drawing Files", filter, 0)
If UBound(fileNames) > 0 Then
    For i = 1 To UBound(fileNames)
        lstDwgList.AddItem fileNames(0) & "\" & fileNames(i)
    Next

End If
```

End Sub